# How to delete duplicated rows using a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data in my ***BookAuthor*** table:

| Bookid | AuthorId | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | NULL | DELETE |
| 34 | 2 | KEEP |
| 34 | 3 | KEEP |
| 35 | NULL | KEEP |
| 35 | NULL | KEEP |
| 36 | 2 | KEEP |

I want to delete some wrong data that has duplicated BookId with a NULL AuthorId but I want to keep the AuthorId that is not null. In this example, I want to remove the row with BookId = 34 and AuthorId = NULL

I have started with the snippet but I don't have the expected result.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BookId ORDER BY CASE WHEN BookId IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS count  
    FROM [BookAuthor] 
) 
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE count > 1
```

**NOTE**  that i only want to delete rows that has same BookId but with an AuthorId IS NULL and only if AuthorId has a NOT NULL value, In that case, i should delete the row with AuthorId IS NULL and keep the ones NOT NULL

Any idea or suggestion how to do it with a CTE or another TSQL approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are on the right track. Just need to change a bit on the `ORDER BY` to check for `AuthorId` `NOT NULL`

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BookId 
                                ORDER BY CASE WHEN AuthorId IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS count  
    FROM [BookAuthor] 
) 
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE count > 1
```

Updated query

```
with cte 
as
(
    select  BookId
    from    BookAuthor
    group by BookId
    having  count(*) > 1
    and     MIN(AuthorId)   is not null
)
select  *
from    cte c
        inner join BookAuthorb  on  c.BookId    = b.BookId
where   b.AuthorId  is null
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1a32b8c8a3138c850ec5841da5c2884)

Comment: This is not what i am looking for since i will also have the authorId with 36. The 36 has no row with NULL AuthorId

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as (
    select bookid 
    from bookauthor b
    where exists (
        select 1 
        from bookauthor b1 
        where b1.bookid = b.bookid 
        group by b1.bookid 
        having count(1) > 1
    )
    and authorid is null
)
delete from cte;
```

Comment: not sure WHY this needs a CTE though, just delete B from bookauthor b ......

but the important part here is using the where exists instead of ROW_NUMBER() which is going to short circuit and should be much better performance wise.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock unfortunately, I couldn't solve this otherwise - I was getting syntax all the time, so I end up with the CTE exactly as the OP wanted.

Comment: try replacing select bookid with delete b, it should work for at least sql2012 forward.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock I'll check this out. Thanks!

Comment: none of your solutions work. I updated my post for a better explanation

Answer (score 1):

use to cte to find the matching patterns

```
declare @tmp as table(BookId int, AuthorId int)

insert into @tmp(BookId,AuthorId)
values(34,NULL),
(34,    2),
(34,  3),
(35,    NULL),
(35,    NULL),
(36,    2);

with cte1
as
(
 select
 ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by BookId,IsNull(AuthorId,0) Order by 
 IsNull(AuthorId,0) asc)  
 RowID
 ,BookId,IsNull(AuthorId,0)AuthorId
 FROM @tmp
 ),cte2
 as
 (
 select
 ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by BookId Order by IsNull(AuthorId,0) asc)  
 RowID
 ,BookId,IsNull(AuthorId,0)AuthorId
 FROM @tmp
 )

 select * from cte2
 where  
 AuthorId<>0
 or
 exists
 (
    select '' from cte1 where cte1.BookId=cte2.BookId
    and cte1.RowID>1
 )


keep output:
RowID   BookId  AuthorId
    2   34      2
    3   34      3
    1   35      0
    2   35      0
    1   36      2
```

--delete from @tmp the compliment set.

Comment: this has no guarantee it won't delete the row with the authorid

Comment: I will add an order by that will put the null on the end of the partition groupings

Comment: none of your solutions work. I updated my post for a better explanation

Comment: you changed the rules.  Of course my code doesn't work now

Comment: you want to skip rows where the authorid is only null and the book id is the same, as in the case to bookid=35

Comment: use two cte tables .  or you can use a cursor and a temp table and make one pass over the data to inspect the data and store the rowid and make a second pass to delete unwanted records.

Comment: I used two cte and produced the results in your grid